# Removing sms before applications like Go SMS Proc reads it in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am making an application which filters text messages if coming from a particular number but the problem is that applications like Go SMS Pro and ChompSMS reads them before they reaches to my app. I don't know how to filter messages even before other applications. ?

I have already tried by setting the priority of my receiver to 1000 and then to highest integer supported by Android but Go SMS Pro still catches messages before my app.

Answer (score 3):

Set your receiver's `android:priority` to something big, like `1000` (max priority. Anything higher than this defaults to `1000`) and then call `abortBroadcast()` if you want to stop the SMS from going any further.

If two apps have a tie on their priorities, then Android gives preference to the one that was installed first. So if the user installed Go SMS Pro before your app, it will receiver the broadcasts before you.

Comment: I have already tried. I have set the priority first to 1000 which is highest priority and then to highest integer value supported by Android but Go SMS Pro still catches the message before my app

Comment: is there any way that even if my application is installed later it can read and delete messages before Go SMS Pro ?

Comment: @RamizRaja Ask the user to uninstall and then reinstall Go SMS Pro. Apart from that, you can't.

Comment: Can we decrease the priority of an app using device admin or we stop execution of app when message from particular number ?

Comment: @RamizRaja Not that I am aware of.